# Analyzing traffic with wireshark. Is firefox blocking or filtering get requests?

Tags: firefox, networking, wireshark

I access the same website with firefox and with chormium browser. And I get this. What is firefox doing? How can I see with wireshark the website Im visiting using firefox?

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
   Get ...
      Host: detectportal.firefox.com
      ....


Hypertext Transfer Protocol
   Get ...
      Host: www.bbc.com
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is captive portal detection that was introduced in Firefox 52. You can disable it by following the instructions on the accepted answer to this [mozilla support ticket](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1169302).

[Captive Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) wikipedia page (so you can decide if you want it on or not)

Comment: I tried disabling but then I can´t see any http request

Comment: what filters are you using in wireshark ? BBC website is a HTTPS site so you need to be looking for ssl traffic. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/HTTPS